# Erlang/Cowboy: erlang.mk:6741: recipe for target ... failed

Tags: makefile, erlang, cowboy

I'm following the guide for [Cowboy](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.4/guide/getting_started/), however, when I run that first `make run` command, I get the following, which I don't understand and can't find any comparable questions online:

```
$ make run
 DEPEND hello_erlang.d
 ERLC   hello_erlang_app.erl hello_erlang_sup.erl
 APP    hello_erlang
 GEN    /home/MyDocuments/hello_erlang/.erlang.mk/relx
erlang.mk:6741: recipe for target '/home/bencotton/Documents/hello_erlang/.erlang.mk/relx' failed
make: *** [/home/me/MyDocuments/hello_erlang/.erlang.mk/relx] Error 35
```

Happy to provide any further details/code.

Comment: *Prerequisites: We are going to use the Erlang.mk build system.* [Installation instructions](https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html)